# Separate incomplete elliptic integral into real and imaginary parts

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

I am working in a problem that involves Incomplete Elliptic Integrals of the First and Second kind of the form $F(\sin^{-1}x~|~m)$ and $E(\sin^{-1}x~|~m)$ where the parameters $m$, $x$ are real numbers in the range $m>1$ and $1/\sqrt{m} \le x \le 1$.

($x$ and $m$ are related to the commonly used argument $\phi$ and modulus $m$ by $x \equiv \sin \phi$ and $m \equiv k^2$)

As can be seen by plotting them, in this range the real part of the integrals is independent of $x$ while the imaginary part isn't. As an example, see [this plot for F](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+EllipticF%5Barcsin%28x%29%2C5%5D+from+1%2Fsqrt%285%29+to+1) and [this other for E](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+EllipticE%5Barcsin%28x%29%2C5%5D+from+1%2Fsqrt%285%29+to+1) for a value $m=5$.

What I would like to do is to separate the real and imaginary part of this integrals, at least in this particular range. In other words, finding the real valued functions $f_{re} (m)$, $g_{re} (m)$, $f_{im} (x,m)$ and $g_{im} (x,m)$ that satisfy:

$$
F(\sin^{-1}x~|~m) \equiv f_{re} (m) + \text{i} f_{im} (x,m)
$$
$$
E(\sin^{-1}x~|~m) \equiv g_{re} (m) + \text{i} g_{im} (x,m)
$$
in the range $m>1$ and $1/\sqrt{m} \le x \le 1$.

By using the Reciprocal Modulus Transformations (see DLMF section 19.7) and taking the limit $x\rightarrow 1/\sqrt{m}$, I have found the real parts to be:

$$
f_{re}(m) \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} K\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)
$$
$$
g_{re}(m) \equiv \sqrt{m} \left[ E \left( \frac{1}{m} \right) - K \left( \frac{1}{m} \right) \right] + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} K\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)
$$

However, the imaginary parts $f_{im} (x,m)$, $g_{im} (x,m)$ escape me. I reckon there should be a way of expressing them in terms of incomplete elliptic integrals with parameters in the real valued range.

If I use the reciprocal modulus transformations I will bring the parameter inside the range $0<m<1$ but the argument will now be complex as I will have $x>1$. I have looked everywhere in the literature but I can't seem to find any identity that solves the problem. I could perhaps do something if there was a way of expressing elliptic integrals of complex argument as a combination of elliptic integrals of real argument and imaginary pure argument, but I don't know how it can be done.

Does someone have any insight on how those imaginary parts could be found?

Comment: Even if this is a zombie comment, I have a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2844415/334505) (the question is also linked) where I managed to make use of Abramowitz & Stegun up to a certain point. Maybe it helps you, or, if you found out the answer, maybe you can hint me? :-)

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the heads up. I never managed to find the answer (although I did move forward in my own specific problem because I only needed to look at some limit values of x and m). Good luck with your question!

Comment: In case you're still interested, I managed to half-deduce/half-hammer a result. It might apply to your case, as well.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I have solved this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reciprocal modulus transformation is Byrd and Friedman 114.01:
$$F(\sin^{-1}x,m)=\frac1{\sqrt m}F(\sin^{-1}x\sqrt m,1/m)$$
$$E(\sin^{-1}x,m)=\frac1{\sqrt m}(mE(\sin^{-1}x\sqrt m,1/m)+(1-m)F(\sin^{-1}x\sqrt m,1/m))$$
Now the parameter is in $[0,1]$ but the sine-amplitude is a real number in $[1,\sqrt m]$. Thus B&F 115.02 applies:
$$F(\sin^{-1}x\sqrt m,1/m)=K(1/m)-iF(A,1-1/m)$$
$$E(\sin^{-1}x\sqrt m,1/m)=E(1/m)-i\left(F(A,1-1/m)-E(A,1-1/m)+\frac{(1-1/m)\sin A\cos A}{\sqrt{1-(1-1/m)\sin^2A}}\right)$$
where
$$A=\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{mx^2-1}}{x\sqrt{m-1}}$$
Note that I have flipped the signs of the imaginary parts from B&F to match the values of $E(\cdot)$ and $F(\cdot)$ as calculated by Mathematica and mpmath. Finally we get
$$F(\sin^{-1}x,m)=\frac1{\sqrt m}(K(1/m)-iF(A,1-1/m))$$

$$E(\sin^{-1}x,m)=\frac1{\sqrt m}\left[mE(1/m)+(1-m)K(1/m)\\
-i\left(F(A,1-1/m)-mE(A,1-1/m)+\frac{(m-1)\sin A\cos A}{\sqrt{1-(1-1/m)\sin^2A}}\right)\right]$$

Comment: 7 years later! Very nice work.

Comment: Great work! Many thanks!